# How to use $scope.go() with typescript in Angularjs1.x?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, navigation

How are you. I am building website using Angularjs 1 with Typescript.
And I am using angular-ui-router framework.
This is simple login controller.
I want to navigate to other page when login success.

```
import {LoginService} from '../services/loginservice';

class LoginController {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  errors:string;
  constructor(public loginService: LoginService) {
  }

  handleLogin() {
    if (this.loginService.login(this.email,this.password)) {
        $state.go('.home');
    }else{
        this.errors = "Wrong username or password";
    }
  }
}

export const Login: angular.IComponentOptions = {
  template: require('./Login.html'),
  controller: LoginController,
  bindings: {
    password: '<',
    email: '<',
    errors: '<'
  }
};
```

But it shows error on $state.go('.home');
So how to go home when login success?
And are there other ways to do it without using $state.go()?
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you forget to inject `$state` in your controller?

Comment: $state.go is definitely the way to go. BUt we need more info to help you. Can you show how you defined your home state, does the state name has a '.' in front of it